# How to fix Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

im learning create fullstack apps and i have a problem with delete the record from database backend request work  however, I can't add a button that will trigger removal

```
const Todo = props => (
<tr>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_description}</td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_responsible}</td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_priority}</td>
    <td className="TableTitle">
        <Link to={"/edit/"+props.todo._id}  className="a_edit"><img src={edit} alt="Edytuj" className="favicon"/></Link>
        <button onSubmit={this.delete}>Usunięcie</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    this.state = {todos: []};
}

delete(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/delete'+this.props.obj._id)
    .then(console.log('Deleted'))
    .catch(err =>console.log(err))
}
```

---

there is a delete method:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.OnRemoveTodo = this.OnRemoveTodo.bind(this);
    this.state = {todos: []};
}
OnRemoveTodo(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/delete'+this.todo._id)
    .then(console.log('Deleted'))
    .catch(err =>console.log(err))
}
```

there is changed const Todo:

```
const Todo = props => (
<tr>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_description}</td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_responsible}</td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_priority}</td>
    <td className="TableTitle">
        <Link to={"/edit/"+props.todo._id}  className="a_edit"><img src={edit} alt="Edytuj" className="favicon"/></Link>
        <button onSubmit={props.OnRemoveTodo}><img src={trash} alt="Usuń" className="favicon"/></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

)

and here is the backend code to which I am trying to appeal

```
todoRoutes.route('/delete/:id').get(function (req, res) {
Todo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, function(err, todo) {
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else res.json('Successfully removed');
});
```

});

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Your delete method is doing a `GET` request. You'll want `axios.delete`

Answer (score 1):

there is no this.delete method.
you are using functional component.
i thing you forgot to use props.delete

```
const Todo = props => (
<tr>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_description}</td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_responsible}</td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : 'TableText'}>{props.todo.todo_priority}</td>
    <td className="TableTitle">
        <Link to={"/edit/"+props.todo._id}  className="a_edit"><img src={edit} alt="Edytuj" className="favicon"/></Link>
        <button onSubmit={props.delete}>Usunięcie</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: change to props help with the cannot read error but after click button nothing happened

Comment: show your delete method  component which mean parent component of Todo